# Is there a word meaning "true-on-average"?

Tags: word-choice

Economist Bryan Caplan [asks](https://twitter.com/#!/bryan_caplan/status/190865146619510785):

> What's a good word for "true-on-average"?

Can we help him out?

Comment: What's the context? Oh...twitter... what's wrong with the suggestions there? Stereotypical? A lie? How about 'the average'?

Comment: Ooo! Let's make up a new word: truverage! :P

Comment: I have trouble wrapping my head around this. Since we only have two values, 1 and 0, nothing in between, that kind of contradicts the whole concept of "average". So I can only suppose we are rounding up. But then "true on average" would encompass everything from "true in 100% of cases" to "true in 50.000000000...01% of cases" (or in short, "true in 50+x% of cases for any x in (0, 50]"). Which is way too broad to be useful at all. Really, we need a clear definition first. Or at least *some* context.

Comment: To best answer this, it would be helpful to have either context, or a definition of "on average".

Comment: "Generally true" is a simple phrase you can use here

Answer (score 3):

According to the Macmillan Dictionary, the phrase *[on average](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/average#on-average)* is already

> used for talking about what is usually true, although it may not be
>   true in every individual situation

So the phrase *true on average* is already concise and idiomatic (and perhaps even redundant), and there's not much to be gained by trying to express it in a single word.

Answer (score 2):

All of the words I first thought of (*[typically](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/typically)*, *[generally](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/generally)*, *[ordinarily](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ordinarily)*, and *[usually](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/usually)*) are somewhat stronger than "true on average", but might serve your purpose anyway.

Comment: Like Reg, I have some problems with "true on average", but I think this is what it is supposed to mean.

Comment: I'm not so sure. *Typically*, *generally*, *ordinarily*, and *usually* are only substitutes for the "on average" part — and stronger substitutes at that, as you note yourself. They do not include the "true" part in any way, shape, form or manner. Something can still be typically wrong, or generally untrue, or usually false.

Answer (score 1):

How about "probable"? It means something is more likely to be true than false.

Comment: Not necessarily -- eg weather people often refer to rain as probable when the likelihood is 30 to 40%.

Comment: @jwpat7 in that case they should be educated on the meaning of the word. Although I can sort of understand their motivation - imagine how much more flak they would get if people got soaked after being told 40% rain was, in fact, improbable.

Comment: Weather people do not refer to rain as probable when it's 40%.